# How to install cordova-google-maps properly in an Ionic 3 project?

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to use [ionic-native/google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/google-maps) and [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) in my Ionic 3 application for both Android and iOS.

1. At first, i got the api keys for both android and iOS from the google developer console.
2. Then installed the cordova map plugin  and ionic native google map plugin using below command:

> ```
> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..." --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="..."
> npm install @ionic-native/core @ionic-native/google-maps
> ```

3. Then, tried to build the project and got below error:

> more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

And, at that time i had these configuration in **config.xml**:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.2.9">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="*******" />
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="*******" />
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="12.0.0" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="24.1.0" />
    </plugin>
```

I googled and found out that, this **PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION** is causing the problem. So, i changed it to **12.0.1** from **12.0.0**. Then again added the platform for android from the start after deleting the node_modules, plugins and platforms folder from the project. But, then i got the below error:

> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzo;

Now, in my **config.xml**, i have

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.2.9">
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="*******" />
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="*******" />
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="12.0.1" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="24.1.0" />
</plugin>
```

So, i again changed the **PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION** from **12.0.1** to **11.6.0**. Now, i can build the project without any error but problem is when i run the project, it is installing the apk in the device but it's not opening the project.

I have also "firebase": "^4.13.1" and "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next" in my **package.json**.

Can anyone point me out what steps should i take to work with google maps in my project?

Answer (score 0):

*P.S. This example is without using plugins.*

Include the Google Maps API in your **src/index.html** file (above the cordova.js file):

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then you can use this in **HTML** file

```
<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map"></div> 
</ion-content>
```

And this in **controller**, for example **home.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor(public _navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap(){

    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.815011, 15.981919);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

  }
}
```

Then you can customize map with **CSS**

```
 home-page {

      .scroll {
        height: 100%
      }

      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

    }
```